# Postgresql initialization error

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos

how do I create a postgresql database cluster with unprivileged user account. I'm using Centos 7.

I have created a user and added them to the 'sudoers' and 'wheel' groups already. I use this user to install postgresql version 10.1 which I do successfully but when I run the initdb command to start the database server I get the error below:

***initdb: could not access directory "/var/lib/pgsql/10/data": Permission denied***

How do I get past this?! Thanks in advance

Comment: please edit your Q to include the contents of `/opt/BIRTiHubFType/iHub/bin/setupOOTBPostgreSQL.xml` . Or at least the blocks containing line  31 and 71. ALSO, can you clean up the formatting of your Q a little. It is not clear to me how `Here is the error:
sudo ./setupiHub.sh .......` is an error message. (While I do see the error message at the very bottom of 60+ lines). AND finally, it seems like you will do yourself a favor by adding a postgres tag to your Q. Good luck.